# Send button does not push intended messages into SQL database using SignalR chat

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

```
<form id ="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <div>


            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

                <ContentTemplate>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="message" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="sendmessage" runat="server" Text="send" OnClick="sendmessage_Click" />

                    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" value="<%= buyer %>" />

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <!-- dISPLAY messages -->   
            <ul id="discussion">
                <% if (chatList != null) {  %>
                    <% foreach (var item in chatList) { %>
                        <li><strong><%=item.buyer %> : </strong></li> <%= item.msg %>
                    <% }  %>
                <% } else { %>
                    <li><strong>No chat</strong></li>
                <% }  %>
            </ul>


            <%--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="red" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>


            </div>
        </form>

<!-- javascript -->
$(function () {
            ....
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (<%= buyer %>, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message. 
                console.log("appended");
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(<%= buyer %>).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

                // Add the message to the page. 
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };

           .....

            // start connection
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#<%=sendmessage.ClientID %>').click(function() {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    console.log("CLicked");
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#<%=message.ClientID%>').val());
                    console.log($('#<%=message.ClientID%>').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#<%=message.ClientID%>').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });

     <!-- Server side to push messages into SQL database -->
     protected void sendmessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        itemid = Request.QueryString["itemid"];
        buyer = Request.QueryString["buyer"];
        seller = Request.QueryString["seller"];
        item = Request.QueryString["item"];
        time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        date = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        msg = message.Text;
        productDAO productdao = new productDAO();
        productdao.push(buyer, msg, Convert.ToInt32(itemid), seller, time, date, item);
    }
```

The first time the send button was clicked, the message are display in the ul tag, which this ul tag is being used to display messages. However, from the 2nd time onwards, its the other way round. The message are pushed into the database but the message is not shown in the ul tag. I have tried using AJAX and other solutions online and nothing seems to work. May i know what has gone wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you check when the 1st message is triggered by the server side push? I am suspicious that you set message to UI from front-end int the first place.

Comment: @Progressive sorry what do you mean by "set message to UI from front-end int the first place"?

Comment: @Progressive I am not sure if i am doing the correct thing you are trying to tell me. BUt that's what i did. I put console.log on both "$('#<%=sendmessage.ClientID %>').click(function().." and "chat.client.broadcastMessage ". For the 1st message, both of the functions are being triggered but not the server side. for the 2nd time onwards, only the server side is being triggered while both of the functions are not(as there is no message displayed on the console.log).

Comment: I think I know what is wrong with your code. your whole function executes when the page loads the first time. This is the default javascript behavior. That's why you set `chat.client.broadcastMessage` in the first place. but then in the server side, you don't push any message to any client. If you could demonstrate a sample to reproduce it, I can try myelf and fix it.